# Function specialization with default arguments can't be called because too few arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, template-specialization, specialization

I have [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7qNXfBW5nq4LWFE3) code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Color: char { Red = 'r', Yellow = 'y', Green = 'g' };

template<Color color>
auto say_my_name(unsigned times = 1) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Color>>(color) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

constexpr auto say_red = say_my_name<Color::Red>;

int main()
{
    say_my_name<Color::Yellow>(3);
    say_my_name<Color::Yellow>();
    say_red(2);
    say_red(); // too few arguments to function
}
```

I want the function `say_red` to be a specialization of `say_my_name`, so I can easily call it in my code, without giving the template argument all the time.

`say_red(2)` works fine, but `say_red()` won't compile with the error message *"error: too few arguments to function"*

Is there a way to let let my code compile without specifing an argument?

---

As a sidenote: I would be possible to convert the template argument to a function argument as well, if that solves the problem. My problem is, that `std::bind` isn't `constexpr` in C++17, so that isn't going for me.
Also I don't want to specify the default argument in every declration of `say_*`. As you can imagine, this is an example, and my "real life" enum has 8 variants, so I want to write as little code as possible.

Comment: The problem is that `say_red` is a pointer to a function with the signature `void(unsigned)` (and this does not carry the default argument), even though the compiler could know to which particular function `say_red` is pointing to it can't know that for every situation. (e.g. if `constexpr auto say_red = get_function_pointer();` it is obtained that way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments are substituted at the call site. They are not part of a functions type. Hence you need "something" to enable the default argument for `say_red`. You can use a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Color: char { Red = 'r', Yellow = 'y', Green = 'g' };

template<Color color>
auto say_my_name(unsigned times = 1) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Color>>(color) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

constexpr auto say_red = [](unsigned times = 1){
    say_my_name<Color::Red>(times);
};

int main()
{
    say_my_name<Color::Yellow>(3);
    say_my_name<Color::Yellow>();
    say_red(2);
    say_red(); // too few arguments to function
}
```

In case you don't mind adding a `()` on each call you can use a functor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Color: char { Red = 'r', Yellow = 'y', Green = 'g' };

template<Color color>
struct say_my_name {
    void operator()(unsigned times = 1) const {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Color>>(color) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

using say_red = say_my_name<Color::Red>;

int main()
{
    say_my_name<Color::Yellow>()(3);
    say_my_name<Color::Yellow>()();
    say_red()(2);
    say_red()(); // too few arguments to function
}
```

and if you do not like the additional `()` you can do this:

```
using say_red = say_my_name<Color::Red>;
constexpr auto red_say = say_red{};

int main()
{
    red_say(2);
    red_say(); // too few arguments to function
}
```

Note that you could also use the constructor instead of `operator()`, but using `operator()` is more flexible as it allows you to return a value. The crux is just to have the specialization and overload resolution in two steps (specialize the functor then call `operator()` with one or zero arguments).

Comment: That's sad, but thanks for the explanation. But as said, that's a way I wouldn't like to go, because I Don't want to repeat the same code over an over again for every enum variant.

Comment: If you want it even shorter, you could hold your nose and use a well-documented temporary preprocessor macro.

Comment: @hellow if this issue is a major concern I would make `say_my_name` a type with `operator()`

Comment: @hellow edited to show alternative. Though I dont completely understand what you want to avoid. You'll need at least `constexpr auto say_red = say_my_name<Color::Red>;` or similar, so whats the deal with a couple of characters more to type?

Comment: @idclev463035818 as you already construct an object, why not just use the constructor, instead of the indirection of the `operator()`? `template<Color color>
struct say_my_name {
    say_my_name( unsigned times = 1 ) { …`

Comment: The deal is the default Argument is [`std::experimental::source_location::current()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location), that's not something I want to repeat over and over and over :D

Comment: @t.niese I was trying to understand what OP is actually after while writing the answer, I think the last part (just edited) would be fine for OP.

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes sure, but if you write it that way [https://godbolt.org/z/rs83n3](https://godbolt.org/z/rs83n3), it would look identical to the original code. That's what I meant.

Comment: What about using the constructor of `say_my_name` instead of `operator()`. That would solve the double `()()`, right?

Comment: @hellow see last snippet, my solution is not the only way to get there, but I believe you cant get it much shorter than that

Comment: @t.niese oh right, now I get what you are saying, that would be a bit simpler. Unfortunately my code just finished compiling ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 That for sure would only work if `say_my_name` should never return anything. And there we are back at the point that it is not fully clear what it should be used for at the end. So your solution might be better.

Comment: Thanks @idclev that's what I wanted to see. Amazing, thanks!

Comment: @hellow Aren't you already repeating it for every enum variant? You have to write `constexpr auto say_(colour) =` for every enum variant.

Comment: @user253751 yes, but not the default Argument, what I wanted to avoid. There has to be some Kind of expressiveness, but no "real repetition".

Comment: I think the expressiveness is that you can write `say_my_name<Color::Red>` instead of `say_red` and then you have no problem.

Comment: `constexpr auto say_red = [](auto... args){ say_my_name<Color::Red>(args...); };` allows to don't repeat default argument.